# Please explain the shell code which is used for executing python files

Tags: python, sh

Can any one explain the below code please?

```
ls  *.py > xx
while [ 1 ]
do
read myline || break
python $myline 
python $myline --genxml 
done<xx
service nac-ms restart
```

Comment: What "explanation" do you need?  What **specific** question do you have?

Comment: I don't consider this a Python question.

Answer (score 7):

It lists all the .py files in the current working directory, and puts the output in file `xx`:

```
ls  *.py > xx
```

Then it loops, reading from xx:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
read myline || break
...
done<xx
```

For each line, `$myline` is set to the value of the line. It runs

```
python $myline 
python $myline --genxml
```

with the value of `$myline` being substituted for $myline on each of the above lines. Then it runs

```
service nac-ms restart
```

---

References:

- [while loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html)
- [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)
- [break](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html)
- [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#IOREDIRREF)
- [Code blocks and I/O redirection example](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#EX8)

---

This code is not very safe if the files have spaces or `\n` characters in their names. For example, if a file is named `which file.py`, then

```
python $myline
```

runs

```
python which file.py
```

instead of

```
python "which file.py"
```

This can be fixed by putting double-quotes around $myline:

```
python "$myline"
python "$myline" --genxml
```

---

If a filename has a `\n` character, then the `ls` command will print the single file name on more than one line. So `read myline` will not slurp the entire filename. Again the script will break.

This problem can be fixed using the pattern

```
find . -iname "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation i want to how does below code works   while [ 1 ]
do
read myline || break
...
done<xx

Comment: I've added some reference links which should help you understand how the code works.